# Change keyboard mapping

Tags: keyboard, remapping

HP Mini 210
    Fedora 14 xfce

I have bought a new HP Mini. I use it for programming in emacs.

However, I want to change the key mapping for the 'fn' and 'ctrl'. Basically I want to swap them around. The 'ctrl' is not in a good position when using emacs. It would be better in the place of the 'fn'.

Is there a way to do this?

Many thanks for any suggestions,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

<kbd>Fn</kbd> keys are usually handled below the operating system, and changing them is generally not possible.